# Fiddler only captures from ipv4.fiddler

Tags: fiddler

I have fiddler running on Win7 64bit, with Capturing turned on for All Processes (in the bottom left).

If I browse to http://ipv4.fiddler then I see the request appear (and a 404 issued as expected).  However, if I browse to *any other* URL, no traffic is captured.  I've tried this in IE, Chrome, and FF (with Fiddler: ON (auto) in the bottom right).

If I open the WinINET options and click on LAN Settings then I can see that the proxy server is enabled.  If I click on Advanced then I can see 127.0.0.1:8888 set for both HTTP and Secure.  There is an exception set for <-loopback>.

So everything looks like it is configured correctly, but still I see no traffic.

If I telnet to 127.0.0.1, 8888 or ipv4.fiddler, 8888 then the connection fails.  I don't know if this is expected or not.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, restarting the machine etc. but still no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ipv4.fiddler only works if Fiddler is actually capturing your traffic, which suggests that you have a filter set somewhere that is hiding the traffic. Check the Filters tab, in particular.

Comment: Thanks Eric - yes I had a filter set.